# h:commandLink target executed before action method

Tags: jsf, richfaces, target

I have a page where you select value and it generates a PDF, On a SelectOneMenu I have values where you can choose to email the PDF or open it in a new tab.

here is my problem:

```xml
<h:commandLink action="#{Reports.filter}" value="Create" styleClass="linkbutton"  target="#{Reports.action eq 0? '_blank':'' }"/>
```

Open in new Tab = 0, email = 1, Same Page = 2. In my method I do a check to see if my List is empty, if he is empty the action gets set to 2, if he is not empty the action remains the original value that was selected. So if my list is empty the page still opens a new tab to try to send a mail where it should "Same Page" to display my notification.

How can I set this up to wait for the Reports.filter method to finish and then get the target value?

I also use richfaces.

Comment: Which jsf version are you using? What's your bean's scope?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your snippet should look like this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="actionSelector" value="#{Reports.action}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Open in new tab" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Email PDF" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<a4j:commandLink action="#{Reports.filter}" oncomplete="reportAction();" />

<h:outputScript>
    function reportAction() {
        if (jQuery("select[id$='actionSelector']").val() === 0) {
            window.open(...);
        }
    }
</h:outputScript>
```

Ie, since `target` gets rendered *before* the user even clicks the link, you have no chance to change that in the right time.